# Sencha Ext JS always return updated value as string

Tags: c#, extjs

I'm running into a problem when i'm using Sencha Ext library

I have a grid with crud options. I bind a object to the grid and when i edit a value which is decimal, double or float value and push update or store.save it always returns a string object.

For example:

In the grid it binds a decimal value 1.567, i edit it in the grid and change it to 1.467 and push update.

When i look into the response object POST i see that the value is now "1.467", hence it is now a value with the type string.

And therefor when i use this method:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Update(List<Investments> data)
{
   //here will be update sql query
}
```

the object that holds the updated data is now 0.0, not 1.467 because i cannot typecast a string to double. The column has a property the defines particular column as type double.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

`Double` is not a valid field type. Instead, use `float` in your store's field config.

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-type

Comment: Ok thank you, but that does n ´t answer the question why the updated field is always returned to the server as string. Because of that, the server object takes the data sent from client and typecast it back to double and ends up with "5.91" > 0.0 (decimal)